# How to compare GDKEvent timestamp with current time?

Tags: c++, gtk

How to use the GDKEvent's timestamp in c++?
For example, I print it as unsigned int, its value is 4194719109, but the current time is 1395764110 which is gotten from time() of time.h. The current time of g_get_real_time() is 1395764110872217 which is a gint64 type value. it seems the g_get_real_time() is more accurate than time().

My purpose is to calculate how many times it has lasted from the time of GDKEvent occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `time` element of `GdkEvent` is in miliseconds. Comparing with `g_get_monotonic_time()` (which is in µs) divided by `1000` should work (make sure to check the sign and cast to `guint32` before comparing)