# What is the timestamp given by GdkEventKey::time relative to

Tags: gtk3, gdk

The documentation sais [1]

> guint32 time; the time of the event in milliseconds.

Relative to what?

- The time since latest event
- Process lifetime
- System boot time

I need to know the time when a key was hit.

[1] https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Event-Structures.html#GdkEventKey

Comment: Maybe add a link to the documentation?

Comment: It uses the same timestamp its backend does (e.g. XLib on linux/xorg), so I don't think you can rely on its value, only compare it to other events timestamps.

Comment: @keltar Does GTK have an API for retrieving a reference timestamp.

Comment: @user877329 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629487/how-to-compare-gdkevent-timestamp-with-current-time says to use `g_get_monotonic_time` and convert it to miliseconds, but I don't see any references saying it is *required* to be so. It probably works on most platforms though.